# Android - WebView covering entire screen

Tags: android, android-webview, android-constraintlayout

I know that there are a lot of questions similar to mine and a few answers, but I've tried everything anc couldn't set my custom WebView perfectly on the screen.

**I've created a custom WebView:**

```
public class ContentView extends WebView {

    Context mContext;
    MenuItem menuItem;
    String name;
    URL url;

    public ContentView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void loadContent(Context context, MenuItem item) {
        menuItem = item;
        name = item.name;
        url = item.url;
        mContext = context;

        String token = SharedPreferencesManager.getToken(mContext);
        Map<String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        extraHeaders.put("Authorization", "Bearer: " + token);

        loadUrl(url.toString(), extraHeaders);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

**And I'm adding multiple instances to my screen:**

```
final MenuItem menuItem = item;
        ContentView contentView = new ContentView(this);
        contentView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        contentView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                contentFinishedLoaded(menuItem);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Adds the content to layout
        ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.activityMainConstraint);
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        layout.addView(contentView);
        set.clone(layout);

        set.connect(contentView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.toolBar, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
        set.connect(contentView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.navigationBar, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
        set.connect(contentView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
        set.connect(contentView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
        set.applyTo(layout);

        // Loading content
        contentView.loadContent(this, menuItem);
```

**This is my AppManifest as requested:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dbl">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I tried:**

- Creating a custom WebViewClient and setting it - doesn't work;
- Changing constraint layout params - I could remove them completly with the same outcome;

My webview is strictly programatical, so no xml involved.

Comment: you can set the width and height right?

Comment: Whatever value I set to the ConstraintLayout, it doesn't work. For a moment it shows up like a horizontal line, with the height of 2-3 pixels and width of the parent, but when it starts loading it get full screen.

Comment: use RelativeLayout or LinearLayout

Comment: You're saying to add the WebView inside RelativeLayout, and put that into the ConstraintLayout? I'll give it a try.

Comment: No take Relativelayout as a parent layout and in Relativelayout define webview with width and height. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to android manifest file and check @theme attribute . You need to change @theme to default styles.

Please share your manifest code for better understanding.

Comment: I added AndroidManifest.xml